# JRuby - include Java vs require "java" - what's the difference?

Tags: jruby

what's the difference between `include Java` and `require "java"`?

Answer (score 2):

require 'java' is called to make all the Java integration facilities available to the script. The require keyword is somewhat similar to the import keyword in Java; it is a signal to load resources from a file whose name follows the keyword

include Java : We include Java API to JRuby.

go through this [link](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=214719)